# C Binary Search Tree pre-order traversal with recursion

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am working on a function that searches through a binary search tree in C for a name that is passed in with the function. However, I am stuck on how to format my loop so that the recusion doesn't simply end when the traversal reaches the left-most node with no children. The traversal has to be pre-order (visit myself, then my left child, then my right child).

My find function is as follows:

```
tnode *bst_find_by_name(tnode *ptr, const char *nom){

    if(ptr != NULL){
        if(strcmp(ptr->name, nom) == 0){
            return ptr;
        }
        if(ptr->left != NULL){
            return bst_find_by_name(ptr->left, nom);
        }
        if(ptr->right != NULL){
            return bst_find_by_name(ptr->right, nom);
        }
    }

    return NULL;


}
```

As you can see, currently this simply returns NULL once it reaches the left-most node that does not match the string that was passed into the function. I have to have it return NULL if it does not find a match in the tree, but at the same time I do not want it to return NULL too early before it has a chance to search every node in the tree. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary variable that holds the return value. And check to see if `bst_find_by_name` returned something other than NULL if it returned NULL continue checking the tree.

Something like the following.

```
tnode *ret = NULL;
if(ptr->left != NULL){
    ret = bst_find_by_name(ptr->left, nom);
}
if(ret == NULL && ptr->right != NULL){
    ret = bst_find_by_name(ptr->right, nom);
}
return ret;
```

Comment: Thats so simple. I have no idea why that didn't come to me. Perhaps after hours and hours of coding you start to experience diminishing returns on what your brain can come up with. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can accept the answer of @FDinoff if it is usefull to you by clicking on the check mark

Comment: This crashes if you pass in an empty tree (ptr == NULL), which should be considered valid input under most circumstances.  See my answer for a cleaner solution (in my opinion)

Comment: @xaxxon There is no NULL checking for ptr in the code I posted because I assumed that the OP would do proper NULL checking as he did it in his original function.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to write it like this:

```
tnode *bst_find_by_name(tnode *ptr, const char *nom) {
    // accept a null node, just exit early before dereferencing it
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // is it this node?
    if(strcmp(ptr->name, nom) == 0){
        return ptr;
    }

    // remember, if the first part is true, || will skip the second part
    return bst_find_by_name(ptr->left, nom) || bst_find_by_name(ptr->right, nom)
}
```

Comment: This won't work because logical or returns 0 or 1. not a pointer to a tnode.

Answer (score 0):

```
// get the matching pointer for left or right subtree, and return 

tnode *bst_find_by_name(tnode *ptr, const char *nom) {
    // accept a null node, just exit early before dereferencing it
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    // is it this node?
    if(strcmp(ptr->name, nom) == 0){
        return ptr;
    }

    tnode * ptrtemp = bst_find_by_name(ptr->left, nom);
    if(!ptrtemp) {
        ptrtemp = bst_find_by_name(ptr->right, nom);
    } 
    return  ptrtemp;
}
```